# Flask+Nginx+uWSGI : ImportError: No module named site

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I installed as the http://www.reinbach.com/uwsgi-nginx-flask-virtualenv-mac-os-x.html link's tutorial and when executing the command `uwsgi --ini deploy/deploy.ini`, the terminal says there was an import error:

Set `PYTHONHOME` to `/virtualenv/sample/`

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

I have set my `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` as

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
export PYTHONHOME=$PYTHONHOME:/Library/Python/2.7
```

I cannot figure out what wrong with it.

Could someone help me with the problem?

The whole info in the terminal is shown as below if it is helpful:

```
(env)ios-devmatoMacBook-Pro:hello ios_dev$ uwsgi --ini deploy/deploy.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from deploy/deploy.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 1.9.10 (64bit) on [Fri May 17 16:42:22 2013] ***
compiled with version: 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00) on 17 May 2013 12:41:07
os: Darwin-11.4.2 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-
1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64
nodename: ios-devmatoMacBook-Pro.local
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /Users/ios_dev/Desktop/sample/hello
detected binary path: /Users/ios_dev/Documents/little/little-web/little_web_dev/env/bin/uwsgi
your processes number limit is 709
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 256
lock engine: OSX spinlocks
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:3031 fd 3
Python version: 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05)  [GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)]
```

Set `PYTHONHOME` to `/virtualenv/sample/`

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

Comment: Why are you setting PYTHONHOME at all? It also should be a single directory and not expressed as a path like you are doing. The empty entry and colon in it would be screwing things up.

Comment: please post the contents of your `deploy/deploy.ini` script.

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton: I saw in the link's tutorial that there is a pythonhome setting sentence, so I just copy that in my file. But I am not sure whether it is needed.

Comment: @kisamoto here is the content of deploy.ini                     [uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
processes = 2
virtualenv = /virtualenv/sample/
module = myapp
callable = app
touch-reload = /virtualenv/sample/hello/

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I resolved the same error message `(ImportError:  No module named site)` that I got while trying the [Django and NGINX tutorial — uWSGI 2.0 documentation](https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html).

Deactivate the virtualenv:

```
deactivate
```

Install uWSGI system-wide (if not already installed system-wide)

```
sudo pip install uwsgi
```

Edit the `uwsgi.ini` file.  I commented out the line with the:

```
home = /path/to/virtualenv
```

Run `uWSGI --ini mysite_uwsgi.ini`.

Comment: I don't know why you would remove the home directive.  This is definitely not the correct answer.  The home directive tells uwsgi which virtualenv to use.  So you'd only remove it if you weren't using a virtual environment.  The ImportError generally means that it can't find the module in the defined virtualenv, so make sure that it exists and the modules are actually present.

Comment: I rolled back your edit - if you want to remove the answer, _delete it_ by using the "delete" link at the left bottom (next to edit). Don't vandalize your own post instead.

Answer (score 1):

I read a lot of document about the question, but get no answer.

By coincidentally, I fix this problem by edit uid and gid as root.

It seem like a permissions problem. I don't know why, but it just work. Remember, it is very unsafe to run a product environment as root.

Comment: You cannot import a module without the correct permissions. To fix this problem use `chown -R user:group /path/to/env` so that the correct owner and group are set for the environment, and set the permissions as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

1、active the virtual you used

2、 pip install uwsgi

this the key action，then the

```
command -v wsgi
```

show this

```
/virtual-path/bin/uwsgi
```

3、use current user to run `uwsgi`, because other user is not active the virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

Im My case I wasn't using virtualEnv. Just using django + ngnix. My solution was removing HOME variable into the *.ini  configuration file:

sudo nano /etc/uwsgi/sites/c_app.ini

```
[uwsgi]
    project = c_app
    uid = ubuntu
    base = /home/%(uid)

    chdir = %(base)/%(project)
    **home = %(base)/%(project)** (REMOVED IT)
    module = %(project).wsgi:application

    master = true
    processes = 5

    socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
    chown-socket = %(uid):www-data
    chmod-socket = 660
    vacuum = true
```

then it works.