# uwsgi + Flask + virtualenv ImportError: no module named site

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv, uwsgi

(Other posts on SO are similar, but none have the specific combination of uwsgi + Flask + virtualenv) ([This one is closest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605048/flasknginxuwsgi-importerror-no-module-named-site))

I installed uwsgi via apt-get.  I also tried pip install wsgi.  Both gave me the same issue.

Test command:

```
sudo uwsgi -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock -w myapp:app -H myvirtualenv
```

Result:

```
Python version: 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19, 2013, 18:35:44)  [GCC 4.7.3]
Set PythonHome to myvirtualenv
ImportError: No module named site
```

I can otherwise run my app in the virtual env.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**See the answer from @JRajan first.**

If you're sure you just want to *suppress* the error and not actually *solve* the underlying issue, you should add `--no-site` to your command or `no-site=true` to your uwsgi.ini file.

Comment: @hughes by the way what does '--no-site' mean?

Comment: uwsgi -help | grep "no\-site" yields " --no-site  do not import site module". uWsgi docs aren't much help either: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html?highlight=site

Comment: I doubt this actually fixed your issue.  The "no module named ..." import error generally means that uwsgi doesn't have the correct path to the virtualenv.  The no-site flag will stop the virtualenv from loading the site-packages.  So you don't get the error anymore, but uwsgi also doesn't get access to your python virtualenv or ANY of the site packages.  Check your paths!  edit: posted for posterity.  I spent 8 hours yesterday on this...

Comment: @mapcuk @wes I'm pretty sure `--no-site` refers to the internal python site.py module, you can see this module's location by running: `python -c "import site; print site.__file__"`. It contains information about the global python installation. Not including it would mean you are entirely dependent on the virtualenv.

Comment: He said suppress and not fix the problem!

Answer (score 24):

The path to your virtual environment is wrong. That's the reason for this error.

I'm using virtualenvwrapper and my virtual environments are set at ~/.virtualenvs. So in my case, the uwsgi call would look something like

```
sudo uwsgi -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock -w myapp:app -H ~/.virtualenvs/myapp
```

Hope this helps next time someone comes looking for this one.

Thanks to Cody for pointing it out in the comments.

Comment: Thanks.. this helped me today :)

Comment: You're a life savior. Thanks budy

Comment: thanks, the `home` config should be virtualenv path but I wrote the virtual env python location.

Answer (score 15):

In my case the problem was the python version uWSGI tried to use.

My project was written in python 3.4, but I was not specifying this in uWSGI config. So uWSGI tried to use python 2 and tried to import modules from the folder lib/python2.7 inside the virtualenv.

So I received the 'No module named site' error, because all the modules, including the site module, where inside lib/python3.4, not lib/python2.7.

To solve it, i had to do two things:

- Install the python3 plugin for uWSGI, with:
  `apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python3`
- Use it in the .ini config file, with:
  `plugins = python34`

Hope this helps someone with the same problem in the future.

As requested, here follows my .ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
base = /your/app/path

pythonpath = %(base)
module = your_module_name

callable = app #Here you put the name of the variable which holds your app inside your module

home = /your/virtualenv/path
plugins = python34

master = true
processes = 2

uid = www-data
gid = www-data

socket = /path/to/socket
chmod-socket = 660

die-on-term = true

logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

Comment: Where is this .ini config file?

Comment: @luislhl I've added `plugin = python34` yet the `uwsgi.log` still returns `Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:33:43)  [GCC 4.8.4]
Set PythonHome to /home/rootadmin/.virtualenvs/data_collection
ImportError: No module named site`

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen, maybe it's built with different names across Linux dists. Try python3 instead. If it still doesn't work, try searching inside /usr/lib/uwsgi or /usr/lib64/uwsgi for a file named like 'python34_plugin.so', to find out the name.
You could also try to build it yourself: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#bonus-multiple-python-versions-for-the-same-uwsgi-binary

Answer (score 8):

I had the similar issue before. My problem is that I have both python2.x and python3.x on my ubuntu system, and I want my project to run in a virtual env in which python3 environment is installed. How I resolved this issue:

> apt-get install python3-pip
>
> pip3 install uWSGI

That's all.

Comment: +1 I have the same problem on Centos7. I installed uwsgi from pip and plugin from yum (duh). So I had to remove everything out (clean up). Install python3.4, pip3 and uwsgi from pip3.

Comment: This is the ONLY MOST Correct Anwser! I simply run sudo -H pip uninstall uwsgi,  apt-get install python3-pip & sudo -H pip3 install uwsgi. And that fixed the issue!!!!!. Ubuntu 16.04 / 64bit / python2.x system wide / python3.x  project virtual env

Answer (score 4):

If your virtual environment is running on Python3 then you must install uwsgi using pip3, not pip otherwise, version mismatch will create this import problem

```
pip uninstall uwsgi    
pip3 install uwsgi
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when my homebrew updated my Python version to Python 3.7 and it stopped working. What worked for me was `brew info python` - that will show you all your available Python versions. Than I rolled back to Python 3.6.5 using `brew switch python 3.6.5`.

After that I simply reinstalled my uWSGI using:

```
pip3 uninstall uwsgi
pip3 install uwsgi
```

And that solved it. If you're not sure what version of Python you were using, `brew info python` shows you the install dates. Also, you can check using `pip3 list` if your uWSGI is installed for the current version.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**THIS MAY BE BAD FOR SECURITY FOR SEVERAL REASONS. IT WORKS FOR TESTING. BUT REVIEW FOR SECURITY BEFORE USING THIS EXACT SOLUTION IN PRODUCTION**

Another reason this error may occur is permissions related.  If [using an .ini file as described in the official tutorial for uWSGI for django](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#configuring-uwsgi-to-run-with-a-ini-file), you may have created the ini file with a user and group that makes the file inaccessible to the user that's running the process.

Check the owner and permissions for the file and the directory path it's in. Use chown and chmod to set the needed permissions.

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /srv`

`sudo chmod 0775 -R /srv`

In my case, I was using a vagrant box for testing and the default user is "vagrant" while nginx is using www-data for the user and group. I have set the owner of all of the files in the project to the www-data user and group and added the vagrant user to the www-data group.

`sudo gpasswd -a vagrant www-data`

I'm not sure if this is good security practice, so I'll be working with my system admin when the time comes to put it in production. But for my test environment it works.  Either way, permissions will be something to look closely at for many of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same and my problem was with the python version where uwsgi was running. uwsgi was running on python2 yet my virtualenv python path was set to python3. 
This created the conflict, it kept on failing to locate the installed site package.

**Double check the python version where uwsgi is running so that it is the same as that set on your virtualenv.**