# How to use uwsgi when its built monolithic (with plugins baked in) and installed via dnf on Fedora?

Tags: python, fedora, uwsgi

I've been trying to work through the dreaded [no site error on uWSGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391605/uwsgi-flask-virtualenv-importerror-no-module-named-site).

What's happening is that when I specify python3 as a plugin, it always seems to want to load python 2.7 instead.

When I run uwsgi --plugins-list`, I get back:

```
$ uwsgi --plugins-list

*** uWSGI loaded generic plugins ***
gevent
nagios
rrdtool
carbon
corerouter
fastrouter
http
ugreen
syslog
rsyslog
logsocket
router_uwsgi
router_redirect
router_basicauth
zergpool
redislog
mongodblog
router_rewrite
router_http
logfile
router_cache
rawrouter
router_static
sslrouter
cheaper_busyness
transformation_tofile
transformation_gzip
transformation_chunked
transformation_offload
router_memcached
router_redis
router_hash
router_expires
router_metrics
transformation_template
stats_pusher_socket

*** uWSGI loaded request plugins ***
0: python
17: spooler
18: symcall
100: ping
110: signal
111: cache
173: rpc
--- end of plugins list ---
```

On a working CentOS server when I run `uwsgi --plugins-list`, I get back:

```
# uwsgi --plugins-list

*** uWSGI loaded generic plugins ***
corerouter

*** uWSGI loaded request plugins ***
100: ping
101: echo
--- end of plugins list ---

*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.14 (64bit) on [Sun Jan  8 11:42:22 2017] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) on 05 October 2016 20:03:58
os: Linux-3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 24 16:09:20 UTC 2016
```

I got uwsgi installed on Fedora using `dnf`.  On CentOS it came down from `yum`.  I'll be very surprised if the answer to this is to install via pip because that means that the Fedroa stocked version has limited use because it was compiled monolithic.

Answer (score 1):

The uwsgi packages in Fedora and EPEL (for CentOS) are built in a way that most plugins (python, ruby, psgi, php, etc) have to be explicitly loaded.  When you install uwsgi from PyPI, it is built to default to the python plugin.  So in order for it to work when installed via RPM, run it like this:

```
uwsgi --plugin python <then the rest of your normal arguments>
```

or

```
uwsgi --plugin python3 <then the rest of your normal arguments>
```

Comment: This also seems to be the case for latest (3.7) Alpine linux packages.