# uWSGI, ImportError: No module named site on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, uwsgi

[image]

I'm trying to follow the tutorial at http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html. I've gotten everything working down tohttp://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#install-uwsgi-system-wide. I am working with an ubuntu 14.4 instance on amazon EC2:

Without going into my virtualenv , I ran:

```
sudo pip install uwsgi
```

This led to

```
     ############## end of uWSGI configuration #############
     total build time: 24 seconds
     *** uWSGI is ready, launch it with /usr/local/bin/uwsgi ***     

 Successfully installed uwsgi
 Cleaning up...
```

Then I ran:

```
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ uwsgi --ini /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/mysite_uwsgi.ini
 [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/mysite_uwsgi.ini
 *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.9 (64bit) on [Fri Mar  6 16:15:07 2015] ***
 compiled with version: 4.8.2 on 06 March 2015 16:10:06
 os: Linux-3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:22:43 UTC 2014
 nodename: ip-172-31-28-196
 machine: x86_64
 clock source: unix
 detected number of CPU cores: 1
 current working directory: /home/ubuntu
 detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
 !!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
 chdir() to /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp
 your processes number limit is 7862
 your memory page size is 4096 bytes
 detected max file descriptor number: 1024
 lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
 thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
 uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/mysite.sock fd 3
 Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 23:03:41)  [GCC 4.8.2]
 Set PythonHome to /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1
 ImportError: No module named site
 VACUUM: unix socket /tmp/mysite.sock removed.
```

Where is

```
ImportError: No module named site on Ubuntu
```

coming from and how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try running it with sudo?

Comment: Yes, copied it right out of the tut.

Comment: run `sudo uwsgi --ini /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/mysite_uwsgi.ini`

Comment: Same output as before

Comment: I also installed the LTS version at sudo pip install http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-lts.tar.gz. No change

Comment: BTW, just wanted to thank you again for your help this week. I think I got enough to run it in a basic way with my virtualenv. I see that other people have had the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605048/flasknginxuwsgi-importerror-no-module-named-site?rq=1

Comment: It has something to do with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715039/python-interplay-between-lib-site-packages-site-py-and-lib-site-py

Comment: Which python version are you trying to use?

Comment: my virtualenv contains python 3.4

Comment: I have a follow up at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640868/compile-failed-with-error-code-1-in-tmp-pip-build-root-uwsgi, while trying to follow the answer below , if you have time.

Answer (score 1):

Try `no-site = True` in mysite_uwsgi.ini file.

Comment: I've got a new problem while trying to follow your directions. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640868/compile-failed-with-error-code-1-in-tmp-pip-build-root-uwsgi

Comment: I'm not very good with uwsgi. I only had my own problems(installed it few days ago for the first time) and while googling for my solution I found your question. stackoverflow.com/questions/29631136/cant-run-uwsgi-with-ini-file-in-emperraor-mode-permission-denied