# Compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/uwsgi

Tags: python, ubuntu, uwsgi

I'm trying to follow the tutorial at http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html. I've gotten everything working down tohttp://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#install-uwsgi-system-wide. I am working with an ubuntu 14.4 instance on amazon EC2:

Without going into my virtualenv , I ran:

```
sudo pip install uwsgi
```

This led to :

```
----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-64P2dl-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/uwsgi
Storing debug log for failure in /home/ubuntu/.pip/pip.log
```

The log has:

```
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_ubuntu...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-uLEPHb-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hPh8D0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-uLEPHb-build
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 706, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-uLEPHb-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hPh8D0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-uLEPHb-build
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to install something else with pip if pip works correctly. Then (well you should have done it already) try to install some dependencies for uwsgi (but I guess you already did it). `apt-get install build-essential python` or `apt-get install python-dev`.  If it still throws InstallationError you probably will need to find another way to install uwsgi. Or wait till somebody more competent answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it but no luck so far.

Comment: I'm getting the same error for everything I try to install with pip, and I recently changed permissions for the /tmp/ folder. I'm pretty sure that has something to do with it, although I'm not sure why/how to fix it.

Answer (score 9):

May be a little late to answer your question but putting my answer could help people later.

I looked backward at the log and saw these lines.

```
[x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -In file included from plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1:0:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include 
                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

It turned out that it couldn't find Python.h. Installing python2.7-dev fixed the problem for me.

```
apt-get install -y python2.7-dev
```

Comment: Fixed it for me too

Comment: `apt-get install -y python3-dev` also for python3 environments

Comment: I'm using Anaconda for python 3.  I had the same error as the OP (caused by 'LTO version') and it turned out that I had to install different compilers: `conda install gxx_linux-64` and then I could do `pip install uwsgi` successfully

Comment: In some cases ```yum install gcc python36-devel```